# Can't get one field to copy to another

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value of water to copy the value from protein once the user has clicked off from or tabbed away from the protein field.  I checked out a few examples on this site, but was unable to get any of them to work with my code.  I'm sure it's something really simple, I'm just not sure how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-
1252">
<title>Dr. Kosimides Lean Body Academy Calculator</title>
<style>

body
{
    background:#adff00;
}

main
{
    border:2px solid #504E4F;
    padding:5px 5px;
    background:#1BA1E2;
    width:225px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}


h1
{
    color:#9F9D9E
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 24px;
}

</style>
```

```
<form name="lbac" id="lbac">
<main>
  <form>
    <h1>LBA Calculator</h1>
    <div align="center"><label> Weight <input name="weight"
          id="weight" size="5" type="text" autofocus> (lbs) </label>
  <label><p></p>
        Body Fat <input name="bodyfat" id="bodyfat" size="3"
          type="text"> (%) </label></div>
    <div align="right">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
    </div>Recommended Amounts
    <div align="right"><label> Protein <input name="protein"
          id="protein" size="3" type="text"> </label><br>
    </div>
    <div align="right"><label> Water <input name="water" id="water"
          size="3" type="text"> </label>&nbsp; <br>
    </div>
    &nbsp; <br>
    <br>
    <div align="left"><label> Pounds of Body Fat <input name="lbf"
          id="lbf" size="3" type="text"> (lbs) </label><br>
    </div>
    <div align="left"><label> Lean Body Mass <input name="lbm"
          id="lbm" size="3" type="text"> (lbs) </label><br>
    </div>
    <div align="left"><label> Daily Water Intake <input name="dwi"
          id="dwi" size="3" type="text"> (oz) </label><br>
    </div>
    <div align="left"><label> Daily Protein Intake <input
          name="dpi" id="dpi" size="3" type="text"> (g) </label><br>
    </div>
    <input name="Calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="LBAcalc()"
    type="button">
        <input name="Reset" value="Reset" type="reset">
    </form>
    </main>


    <script>

document.lbac.water.value=".5";
document.lbac.protein.value=".5" 
        function LBAcalc()
        {


                 // Get The Input

                var w_txt = document.getElementById('weight');
                var bf_txt = document.getElementById('bodyfat');
                var p_txt = document.getElementById('protein');
                var wtr_txt = document.getElementById('water');


                 // Convert To Numbers If Needed

                var w = parseInt(w_txt.value);
                var bf = parseInt(bf_txt.value);
                var p = parseFloat(p_txt.value);
                var wtr = parseFloat(wtr_txt.value);


                // Convert body fat to percentage

                bf = bf / 100

                // Process and Display Results

                var result = document.getElementById ('lbf');
                var myResult = w * bf;
                result.value = myResult.toFixed(0);

                var result1 = document.getElementById ('lbm');
                var myResult1 = w - myResult;
                result1.value = myResult1.toFixed(0);

                var result2 = document.getElementById ('dwi');
                var myResult2 = myResult1 * wtr;
                result2.value = myResult2.toFixed(0);

                var result3 = document.getElementById ('dpi');
                var myResult3 = myResult1 * p;
                result3.value = myResult3.toFixed(0);


        }



    </script>



        </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `onblur()` method. Which runs code once the focus on that field is lost. I found out that you can't change the value of an element inside the onblur method, so you will have to make a custom method and call it.

```
<input name="protein" id="protein" size="3" type="text" onblur="copyValue(this)">
```

Inside your `<script>` and `</script>` tag and after your `function LBAcalc() { .....}`
Create a new function to copy the value.

```
function copyValue(element) {
     element.value = document.getElementById("water").value;
```

}

Comment: I just looked it up and it seems that you cannot change the value of the field from the onblur method. So what you could do is call a custom js method and pass the element as the argument. `onblur="changeValue(this)"` remember 'this' is your input element, so here is your method: ` changeValue(element) {element.value = document.getElementById("water").value;}`

Comment: I'm not really sure where to put this in the coding?  I have zero experience with coding.

Comment: Let me reword my answer so that It will show up correctly

Comment: Still unable to make this work.  Here is the website I'm trying to do this for.  http://drgeorgekosmides.wix.com/leanbodyacademy

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding the use case, but here goes:

```
<input name="protein" id="protein" size="3" type="text" onchange="copyValue(event)">
```

The 'onchange' event fires when the value has changed. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change): When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not commited (e.g. after editing the value of < textarea > or < input type="text">)

So, then we just write up an onchange handler:

```
function copyValue(event) {
    document.getElementById('dwi').value=event.target.value
}
```

That will copy the value from the element that fired the event (i.e. the protein input), and copy it to the element that has the ID of DWI.

Alternatively, you could listen to a blur event and then run a 'setTimeout' of a half second, and then run the code to copy from protein to dwi. Blur would run every time the person left the field, whereas change only causes the copy to happen when there was an actual change (i.e. 6 -> 7)